# How do I use a script to fill-color-yellow all of certain numbers I choose in google sheets?

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I want to fill-color-yellow all of the prime numbers (within a certain range) in a google spreadsheet that I am working on. I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Do you want to do it by running a script or conditional formatting? You'll need at least a function that determines if a number is prime which you should be able to find plenty of JS resources for.

Answer (score -1):

```
function isPrime(value) {
    for(var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return value > 1;
}

function testcolorPrimes()
{
  colorPrimes('#ffff00');
}

function colorPrimes(color)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('colorprimes');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(!isNaN(rngA[i][j]))
      {
        if(isPrime(rngA[i][j]))
        {
          var range = sht.getRange(i+1, j+1).setBackground(color);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```